# Java & Hibernate - Session Management while using Interface

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, inheritance

I'm having an issue with the following code, please I need help.
In the service layer while using Hibernate I am using annotations to manage the sessions, which is perfectly working.

```
@Override
@Transactional
public Response delete(Integer id) throws Exception {
    Response response = new Response();
    try {
        response.setData(videoDao.delete(id));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
}
```

Which calls the following method in the DAO Layer

```
@Override
    public boolean delete(int id) throws Exception {
        String query = "UPDATE " + this.entity +
                " SET remove_date = '" + String.valueOf(new Date(0)) + "'" +
                " WHERE id = " + id;
        Query q = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(query);
        return q.executeUpdate() > 0 ? true : false;
        }
```

Where videoDao is the Dao layer for an entity that implement an interface. So far so good.

The issue is when I have another method in videoDao that is not in the interface I'm implementing, in that case, the annotation is not working but I don't know how to manage the sessionFactory in the service layer. I think I'm not having the issue when using the method that are in the Interface because Spring is injecting the istances, which include sessionFactory, but if I do it manually (because I cannot use the injected object as it is the interface and not the real class that has this method) the sessionFactory is always null.

```
public interface IDao {
    public boolean delete(int id) throws Exception;
}
```

This is how I define the dao with the Interface in my service layer:

```
@Autowired
IDao videoDao;
```

Comment: Could you show a code example where you cause a null sessionFactory?

Comment: @Faabass Since you are autowiring `IDao videoDao`, how are you able to call the `another method` that is not specified in the interface?

Comment: What do you mean 'the annotation is not working' ? Please post the code of your videoDAO class, and with the not-inherited method that supposedly is not working

Comment: @Madhusudana Reddy Sunnapu yes, I know it sounds stupid, but the way I think it will works is to replace the Interface for the class but that change will be against best practises I guess. I have somethink like 
IDao videoDao = new VideoDao();
but the methods that videoDao has are the one for IDao not for VideoDao

Comment: @Faabass You are right and it would be against best practices. Regardless do find my answer below and see if that helps in anyway for your problem.

Comment: Please provide the proper code to replicate your problem, not only method and interface definition. Only with that info we could see where the issue lies.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize my understanding of what you are looking for - You want to have Spring proxy the methods defined in the class rather than methods defined in the interface implemented by that class.

With the above assumption, the behavior that you are observing is in line with Spring AOP proxy generation.

Spring AOP proxy generation **by default** uses:

1. JDK dynamic proxies if the target class implements at least one interface.
2. CGLIB proxies if the target class doesn't implement any interface.

So with JDK proxies the Spring AOP uses the target interface(s) to find the methods that needs to be proxied. And the Spring JDK proxy implements only the methods defined in the interface(s). So if there is any method that is defined directly in the target class but not in the interface(s), those will not be proxied and this is the behavior you are observing.

With CGLIB option, Spring generates CGLIB proxies only if the target class doesn't implement any interfaces. This CGLIB proxy extends the target class and so proxies the methods in the target class.

This is the default behavior.

But if we want to inform Spring to generate CGLIB proxies even for interface based target classes, we can do so by using `proxy-target-class=true` or `proxyTargetClass` attribute. With this Spring AOP proxies the methods defined in the class rather than looking at the interface(s) and I presume this is what you are looking for.

As you have already indicated, for this to work we need to use/inject the class in your code rather than interface, although not a best practice.

You can find more information on this subject at http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-proxying 
and 
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#transaction